# CSS mask max-height bug

Tags: css, ipad, debugging, landscape, mask

So my problem is with using a css mask to hide a `position: fixed;` item. Reason being because apparently `overflow: hidden;` doesn't work. So this actually works swimmingly in all the browsers I've tested it in UNTIL the height of the div containing the mask reaches a specific, seemingly arbitrary, height. ( 1280px on iPad, 2000px in desktop Safari )

I'm totally stumped on this and haven't found anyone with any documentation on this issue. Has anyone worked with css masks at all to maybe have some clues as to why this is the case?

Here's a screencast demoing the bug and the code used to generate it.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bxzsmkqgll1yeix/Screeny%20Video%20Feb%2010%2C%202014%2C%209.18.28%20PM.mov

And here's a zip with the code used in that demo.
http://cl.ly/Tqy7

Any ideas or proposed solutions?

--- HTML ---

```
<div class="attn hairline"></div>

<div class="shadow"></div>

<div id="home">
    <div class="attn blur"></div>

    <div id="content">
        <p>Hey, here is some awesome content, stuff you will definitely want to read.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

--- CSS ---

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
html, body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.attn {
position: fixed;
width: 80%;
height: 100%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -40%;
background: no-repeat center;
background-size: 100% auto;
}
.hairline {
background-image: url(../img/attn.svg); 
}
.blur {
background-image: url(../img/blur.png);
}
.shadow {
position: relative;
height: 20px;
margin-bottom: -20px;
box-shadow: 0px -3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
top: 100%;
}

#home {
position: relative;
top: 100%;
background: #fff;
mask:         url(../img/mask.svg);
-webkit-mask: url(../img/mask.svg);
-o-mask:      url(../img/mask.svg);
-ms-mask:     url(../img/mask.svg);

/* 1281px will kill the mask on iPad, 2001px will kill it on the desktop */
height: 1280px;
}
#content {
padding: 10% 5%;
}
```

Comment: While this is the first time I've seen a screen-cast used to describe a bug, one of the ideas behind SO is to build a community database of problems and solutions. Is there any chance you can post relevant sections of code as well as a better description of the problem, along with your screencast, please?

Comment: I've never tried making masks with SVG files, but we have a lot of pretty smart people around here, hopefully someone else can give it a go! I'll keep my eye out for possible solutions, however.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was setting a max-height attribute on the masked element until that element got to the top of the browser window. I had the fuzzy image text disappearing at this point anyway so it was a good time to, once the image was gone, remove that max-height attribute. Works great, though I'd still love to solve the original problem someday. I'm guessing its a browser quirk though seeing as how it was so arbitrarily consistent.